# Windows Explorer - Using icons (not thumbnails) for specific files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, icons

How can I force Windows to use icons (not preview thumbnails) only for specific file types?

For example, I want to use an icon for all PPTX files, but a preview   thumbnail for all PNG files.

The closest solution I found was "File Explorer Options -> View -> Always show icons, never thumbnails", but that applies to all file types indiscriminately.

Thank you

Comment: You could create a batch script that starts the program using `c:\program files\Microsoft office\office16\root\powerpoint.exe %1` and then associate PPTX with your batch script. but that may give you the wrong icon. You possibly can fix that by creating a shortcut to the batch script, give that an icon, and open with the shortcut. Note that repairing office will undo this change.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the thumbnail handler for `.PPTX` files from the registry?